# Value was either too large or too small for an Int16 ,when copy to data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, informix, overflowexception

Q:

The following code:

```
        var dtInstTotal = dtExternal.AsEnumerable()
                    .Union(dtEmployed.AsEnumerable())
                    .OrderBy(d => d.Field<string>("emp_name"));

        dtInst = dtInstTotal.CopyToDataTable();//exception
```

throw an exception:

> Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.Couldn't store
>   <103930> in emp_num Column.  Expected type is Int16. --->
>   System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for
>   an Int16.

Comment: What are `dtExternal` and `dtEmployed`? What types do they have for the `emp_num` columns?

Comment: `DataTable dtExternal = Instructor.GetAllAssignedTeachersForImport(int.Parse(ddl_batch.SelectedValue), int.Parse(Session["empnum"].ToString()));
            DataTable dtEmployed = Instructor.GetAllNominatedTeachersForImport(int.Parse(ddl_department.SelectedValue), int.Parse(ddl_study.SelectedValue));`

Comment: And what is the type of `emp_num` in each of the resulting data tables? (Just showing us that they're coming from method calls doesn't really give us much more information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `dtExternal` has a `short` type for `emp_num`, whereas `dtEmployed` has some other type (`int`, `long` or maybe just `ushort`) - or maybe vice versa. `CopyToDataTable` just uses the types from the first table containing the first row it sees, and then it's having problems when it comes across a value for a column with the same *name* from a different table. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx):

> The schema of the destination table is based on the schema of the first DataRow row in the source sequence. The table metadata is extracted from the DataRow metadata and the table values from the column values of the DataRow.

Basically: make sure your two original tables have the same schema.

EDIT: We don't know what your methods to populate the two original `DataTable`s look like - but you may find that by creating the `DataTable` first, explicitly setting the type of `emp_num`, and *then* filling the table, that will be okay.

You could even leave your original methods alone, and build a new `DataTable` with the right schema, then call

```
dtInstTotal.CopyToDataTable(tableWithCorrectSchema, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
```

Comment: yeah this right `dtEmployed` emp_num is small integer

but the DB admin told me he can't change the data types .so please how to fix this programatically .

Comment: There is no magic you can apply. You can't "fix it programmatically" such that the value 103930 fits in a 16-bit integer.

Comment: Can i create my own datatable programatically and put the datatype to int32 instead ?

Comment: @just_name: Well we still don't know the details of how your two methods are getting the data from the database. You've told us that one is using a simple query and one is using a stored procedure, but there's still the code within the methods to fetch that data which we're missing... you *may* be able to just change the method to explicitly specify the type of `emp_num` in the `DataTable`.

Comment: i just call`dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());` to return datatable

Comment: @just_name: But that suggests you've already created the `DataTable` - so give it the schema you want before you load it.

Comment: `dtInstTotal.CopyToDataTable(tableWithCorrectSchema, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);`

return type  is void !!!

Comment: I get it sorry .`tableWithCorrectSchema` is the result .

Answer (score 1):

i think the datatable structure in dtInst or dtInstTotal for emp_num is `int16` change it to `int32`